# Why is my jade plant dying?

Tags: indoors, dryness, jade

I got a jade plant from a local nursery, which was in good health. I was under the impression that I can keep jade plants indoors, so I kept it on my desk. In around a month or so all the leaves dried out.

Is it because I am keeping it indoors all the time? What should I do to make it healthy again? 
Is it really not an indoor plant?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Few questions: if  you repotted  into that greenish container, what soil did you use? Does the container have drainage holes? How much daylight has the plant been getting?  How often have you watered it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can keep a jade indoors, but it does require bright light..much more than any artificial office light will offer.  It looks like you used soil from the great outdoors rather than a potting mix which is also a problem for a jade and for most container grown plants in general.  This plant is not looking too hot.  My suggestion would be to take it out of that pot and rinse all of the native soil off of it.  Repot it this time with a well draining potting soil.  Preferably a type specific to succulents.  If you can't find that then that's ok, just let the soil dry out between watering!  After you repot it, set it by a bright window out of direct sun and hopefully your jade will have enough oomph to push out some new leaves.  It probably will, jades are tough.  Good luck

If you want a plant that could handle your desk with limited light you have few options, but still some decent ones.  Lucky bamboo, snake plant and pothos.  If it were me, I would go for snake plant.

Comment: re potted the plant with more drainable soil this morning and already got a new snake plant for my desk, until this Jade got healthy again.

Answer (score 3):

Your jade plant is dying because of lack of sunlight and too much watering. Jade plant in my area can survive hot summer days with minimum watering, its leaves will turn a slight red to indicate it is getting a lot of sun and will look wrinkly when needs water. So indoor jade plant will start shed leaves and yellowing if gets too much water and not enough sunlight.